# Show that the equality $|z_2 -z_1|^2=|z_2-z_0|^2+|z_1-z_0|^2$ implies $z_2-z_0=iλ(z_1-z_0)$ where λ is real and vice versa

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried this

$|z_2 -z_1|^2=|z_2-z_0|^2+|z_1-z_0|^2= with z_0, z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$

$=-z_2 \overline z_1-z_1\overline z_2 + z_1 \overline z_1 + z_2\overline z_2=-z_2 \overline z_0-z_0\overline z_2 + z_0 \overline z_0 + z_2\overline z_2 -z_1 \overline z_0-z_0\overline z_1 + z_1 \overline z_1 + z_0\overline z_0=$

$=-z_2 \overline z_1-z_1\overline z_2=-z_2 \overline z_0-z_0\overline z_2 + z_0 \overline z_0 +z_0 \overline z_0-z_0\overline z_1 - z_1 \overline z_0=$

$=-z_2 \overline z_1-z_1\overline z_2+ z_2 \overline z_0 + z_0\overline z_2 - z_0 \overline z_0 -z_0 \overline z_0+z_0\overline z_1 + z_1 \overline z_0=0=$

$=\overline z_1(z_0-z_2) + \overline z_0(z_2-z_0)+\overline z_0(z_1-z_0)+ \overline z_2(z_0-z_1)=0=$

$=(\overline z_0-\overline z_1)(z_2-z_0)+(\overline z_0-\overline z_2)(z_1-z_0)=$

$(z_2-z_0)=(z_1-z_0)\frac{\overline z_0- \overline z_2}{\overline z_0- \overline z_2}$

Can you help me from here? I don´t know how to continue

Comment: If you interpret $z_2,z_1,z_0$ as vertices of a triangle, then this looks awfully like the Pythagorean theorem...

Comment: there is a typo towards the end. if you let $w=\frac{z_2-z_0}{z_1-z_0}$, you should get $w+\bar{w}=0$ and therefore $w$ is a pure imaginary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|z_2 -z_1|^2=|z_2-z_0|^2+|z_1-z_0|^2~~~~(1)$$
Clearly $P(z_2),Q(z_1),R(z_0)$ are satisfying Pythagoaras, where $PQ=|z_2-z_1|$ is hypotnuse, $PR=|z_1-z_0|$ and $QR=|z_2-z_0|$ are lengths of normal sides, the angle $R$ is 90 deg. This means  PR and QR are perpendicular so their comlex slopes sum to 0.
$$\implies \frac{z_2-z_0}{\bar z_2-\bar z_0}+\frac{z_1-z_0}{\bar z_1- \bar z_0}=0 \implies \frac{z_2-z_0}{z_1-z_0}+\frac{\bar z_2-\bar z_0}{\bar z_1- \bar z_0}=0 \implies \frac{z_2-z_0}{z_1-z_0}=i \lambda, \lambda \in R~~(2).$$
So (2) follows from (1).
Next, we show the reverse by getting (1) from (2):
$$\frac{z_2-z_0}{z_1-z_0}-1=-1+i \lambda \implies |z_2-z_1|^2 =|z_1-z_0|^2+\lambda^2|z_1-z_0|^2=|z_1-z_0|^2+|z_2-z_0|^2.$$

It completes the proof.